# Hazelcast NodeExtensionFactory always defaulting to DefaultNodeExtension

Tags: hazelcast

I am implementing custom "com.hazelcast.instance.impl.NodeExtension" and updating META-INF/services/com.hazelcast.instance.impl.NodeExtension with custom implementation in newly created Jar project. This Jar project also included with dependency of hazelcast.

New implementation is not taking effect when starting new hazelcast instance. "com.hazelcast.core.server.HazelcastMemberStarter" always using DefaultNodeExtension to start instance. Appreciate any help on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your Jar is loaded before the Hazelcast jar (it's first on the classpath). Otherwise, the application may still read the `META-INF/services/com.hazelcast.instance.impl.NodeExtension` file from the Hazelcast jar.